# Best way to protect a new fence from weather before it can be stained

Tags: fence, stain

I just installed a new fence and now it's supposed to rain every day for 10 straight days.  Woohoo!!

The stain guys can't come out for 5 weeks.  And the fence is not supposed to be stained for at least 2 weeks.  Right now my poor expensive new fence is soaking up rain water.  I'm worried these downpours are going to destroy my new fence.

Is there anything I can do to protect my fence from getting destroyed in the meantime?

Fence Notes:

8ft cedar, board on board 
Has a top cap, double trim, and washer head screws 
126 linear feet of unstained fence.

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide the wood, height, and rough length of the fence?

Comment: @chris Updated question

Comment: the wood could be finished immediately if it weren't for the rain. That being said, you should sand it before finishing whether it's same day or two months down the road. I've seen cedar decks last for a decade when untreated in a four seasons climate. What I'm getting at is you don't have to worry.

Comment: How should it be sanded?  Grit, machine sand, light sand?

Comment: you're working with a bit of fence, generally the stain with state how to prep the wood for the finish. In the even that it doesn't, the quick (it works well, but not recommended way) is to sand it with an orbital sander to a finish grit higher (finer) than 100, preferably 120-150 and blow it off with an air compressor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cedar does not need to be stained, if you don't mind it weathering to gray; that's part of the point of using cedar.

Or you can stain it after it has dried out a bit.

No rush.

Comment: Don't even have to wait, cedar will always take stain from day one.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, but staining in the rain is unpleasant, and staining before/during installation is not always practical.

Comment: ahh hah. I figured you meant the wood naturally drying out, not from the rain!